# Retrieving key of a Map (Stanford C++ Libraries)

Tags: c++, dictionary

I am using the Map type from the Stanford libraries. And I can easily get values, by passing it `.get(key)` But it occurred to me that it would be beneficial if I could retrieve it´s `keys` as-well. Is there a way of doing this?

According to it´s doc at: http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs106b/materials/cppdoc/Map-class.html it does not have such functions. But is there another way of doing it?

Maybe using an iterator: `Map <string, int>::iterator` ?

Comment: Retrieve all of them or a key by value?

Comment: All of them, many of the values are the same. Or let´s say I am iterating through it and getting the values using an iterator. At the same time, I want to retrieve the key for that value and store it elsewhere, if it makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is. Try [`foreach`](http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs106b/materials/cppdoc/foreach.html):

> As a simplification when iterating over maps, the foreach macro iterates through the keys rather than the key/value pairs.

Comment: Great! that one is gonna be really helpful

Answer (score 1):

Your map.h includes a comment:

```
Additional Map operations
 - Iteration using the range-based for statement, standard STL iterators, and the mapping function mapAll
```

so, I guess you could try iterating with iterator:

```
Map<string, int> :: iterator it;
for(it = m.begin(); it != m.end(); ++it){ // Here m is your Map variable.
       string key = it->first;
       //... do something
}
```